# How is it possible to create a circle in CSS that always keeps the same size?

Tags: css, reactjs, geometry, styled-components

I have the problem that I have a circle that adjusts according to the content of the text. However, I would like the font size to adjust to the circle and not have the circle change size.

How is it possible to implement this in CSS?
I use react 18 and styled-components.

Examples of how it should not be.

Please note that the circle should remain a circle on any device.

I hope for your ideas

[E10 (cicle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPHMY.png)

[Diesel (not a cicle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIDFR.png)

Comment: Please add enough runnable code to your question so we can see for ourselves. You are likely to need some JavaScript to calculate the required font size. Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need a bit of avaScript for this.

Here's a simple example. The size of the text is gradually increased until it is wider than you want, then decreased by 1 for the texts in each circle.

```js
const tester = document.createElement('div');
tester.setAttribute('class', 'tester');
document.body.append(tester);
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
circles.forEach(circle => {
  let fs = 2; // 1px is the smallest we can go
  tester.innerHTML = circle.innerHTML;
  tester.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';
  let w = window.getComputedStyle(tester).width.replace('px', '');
  while (w < 40) { //allow for some space left and right so not the full 50
    fs++;
    tester.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';
    w = window.getComputedStyle(tester).width.replace('px', '');
  };
  circle.style.fontSize = (fs - 1) + 'px';
});
tester.remove();
```

```css
.circle {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tester {
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">text</div>
<div class="circle">longer text</div>
```